# How to properly fread() and fwrite() a non text file?

Tags: c++, fwrite, fread

This is my first approuch with `fread()` and `fwrite()` functions. So I am stil  learning how to deal with them. For text files I've sucessfully managed to read a and then create a file in another function. But, whenever I try it out with non text files they just output corrupted. I am asking here because I've had no sucessfull results searching this matter over internet.

In short: I am sending the data collect from the file I opened at a server to a client, and then the client tries to create the exact file with the data parsed.

So, let me explain how I am doing this:
I open a non text file in binary mode:

```
FILE* myfile = fopen(fullPath.c_str(), "rb");
```

Then I create a loop to read over the file: (for some reason I've found out that the real size of a non text file is equal to `size/4`)

```
int readPos = 0;
std::string externalBuffer;

while (true) {
    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    bytesRead += fread(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char), 1024, upfile);    

    if (bytesRead == 0)
        break;

    externalBuffer = unsigned_char_to_string(buffer, bytesRead); //This simple function loops over the buff and converts each entry to the string -> the results are numbers from 0-255

//Here I convert the buffer to a string and send it to the client to be parsed and add to a string buffer like: dataChunk += parsedString;

//clear buffers

}
```

Now I am parsing sucessfuly the string at the client (I am not sure if the corruption problem lies at my conversion of the buffer to a string).
After all data from the loop is sent. The client tries to write then using the buffer dataChunk:

```
FILE* myfile = fopen(fullPath.c_str(), "wb+");
fwrite(dataChunk.c_str(), sizeof(char), dataChunk.size(), myfile);
fclose(myfile);
```

I've already tried to convert the data sent to hexadecimal string, converting each entry from 0-255 to its hexadecimal and writing to the new file. I also tried to convert the `dataChunk` string to a `unsigned char` array. But all my attempts led to a corrupted file. I used this method to attempt create a executable file and a png image.
I've also saw some examples that then `fopen` and copy all file at once and then `fwrite` at a new created file at the same function using unsigned char that looks like it worked for them.

So, what is wrong with this code and why it's not outputting a perfect file? Am I using `fread()` and `fwrite()` wrongly?

Comment: What does "they just output corrupted" mean?

Comment: Why are you using `stdio` functions in a C++ program, instead of C++ classes?

Comment: @immibis the files does not execute as it should. It doesnt have the size it should. I think that is it.

Comment: @Barmar as I said, its my first approuch to it. Any guidance is welcome! :)

Comment: "I've found out that the real size of a non text file is equal to size/4". No it isn't.

Comment: When you call `unsigned_char_to_string()`, the second argument should be `bytesRead`, not `sizeof(buffer)`.

Comment: It would be `size/4` if you were reading 4-byte objects with `fread()`. But you're reading `unsigned char`, so they should be equal.

Comment: @Barmar, well If It loops like "while (size > readPos)", readPos never reaches size, it gets stuck at size/4. I will correct the unsigned_char_to_string(). Thank you Barmar.

Comment: How did you get to the end of the file in the first place, so that `ftell()` would tell you the size of the file?

Comment: Why don't you just loop until `fread()` returns `0`, which indicates EOF, instead of checking against `realSize`?

Comment: @Barmar, yes. I used ftell() to get the size of the file and I supposed that it  could be the end of the file because It worked for text files.

Comment: Ill do it, seems a better strategy.

Comment: @Xabirau When you first open the file, `ftell()` will return `0`. You have to go to the end of the file first, e.g. with `fseek(myfile, 0, SEEK_END)`

Comment: @Barmar, I will just avoid ftell and use the loop "while (true) with a break when fread returns 0." Seems best. Ill edit the code now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Barmar just tested with the current changes. The files are still corrupted but now getting a higher size than it should be. Like the .exe file Im testing has 4.4mb, after creating with the data parsed it sizes 7.04mb. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Barmar corrections.
I changed the unsigned_char_to_string function to this code:

```
std::string externalBuffer(&buffer[0], &buffer[0] + bytesRead);
```

and it worked perfectly!

Thank you @Barmar! Sorry for being noobish :) You made my day!